# Null response in query for Relay Modern interogation on GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, graphql, graphql-js, relaymodern

Maybe someone who has managed to pass this step is willing to provide some indications.

I have a schema, a resolver, i request the query and i have a null response.
Please can you help on topic?

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    allLinks: async (root, {filter}, {mongo: {Links, Users}}) => {
      let query = filter ? {$or: buildFilters(filter)} : {};
      return await Links.find(query).toArray();
    }
```

and the query request looks like this:

```
    query LinkListPageQuery {
  allLinks {
    ...LinkList_allLinks
  }
}

fragment LinkList_allLinks on LinkConnection {
  edges {
    cursor
    ...Link_link
  }
}

fragment Link_link on LinkEdge {
  node {
    id
    description 
    url
  }
}
```

My schema looks like this:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Link implements Node {
      id: ID!
      url: String!
      description: String!
      postedBy: User
      votes: [Vote!]!
    }
    interface Node {
      id: ID!
    }
    type Query {
      allLinks(filter: LinkFilter, first: Int): [LinkConnection]
      node(
        id: ID!
        ): Node
    }
    type LinkEdge {
      node: Link!
      cursor: String
    }
    type LinkConnection {
      pageInfo: PageInfo
      edges: LinkEdge
      count: Int
    }
    input LinkFilter {
      OR: [LinkFilter!]
      description_contains: String
      url_contains: String
    }
    }
  `;
```

PS: This language schema is done according to `graphql-tools` package.

**Resolver:**

```
 Query: {
        users: async (root, { first, after }, { mongo: { Users }, user }) => {
          const queryData = await Users.find(query).toArray();
          first = first || queryData.length;
          after = after ? parseInt(fromCursor(after), 10) : 0;
          const edges = queryData.map((node, i) => ({
            cursor: toCursor(i+1),
            node: node._id,
          })).slice(after, first + after);
          const slicedUser = edges.map(({ node }) => node);
          return {
            edges,
            pageInfo: {
              startCursor: edges.length > 0 ? edges[0].cursor : null,
              hasNextPage: first + after < queryData.length,
              endCursor: edges.length > 0 ? edges[edges.length - 1].cursor : null
            },
            count: queryData.length,
          };
        },
UserConnection: {
    edges: ({ edges }) => edges,
    pageInfo: ({ pageInfo }) => pageInfo,
    count: ({ count }) => count,
  },

  UserEdge: {
    node: async ({ node },data, {dataloaders: {userLoader}}) => {
      const user = await userLoader.load(node);
      return user;
    },
    cursor: ({ cursor }) => cursor,
  },
```